# Javascript animation. Move div on hover between points

Tags: javascript, css

I need to move red circle around the flash on hover, but when cursor is out it mast move back to start point. How I can do pauses in loop? Maybe is another way to do this animation?

```js
var circle = document.querySelector('.circle');    
var wayPoints = [[32.3,23.3],[42,42],[45.5,36.5],[55.2,53.7],[57.8,49.2],[73.5,78.5],[52.5,61],[50.5,65.5],[39,52],[36.5,56],[22.5,44.8]];

circle.addEventListener('mouseover', moveCircle);
//circle.addEventListener('mouseout', backCircle);

function moveCircle(){
    for(i in wayPoints){
        circle.style.top = wayPoints[i][0];
        circle.style.left = wayPoints[i][1];
    }
}
```

```css
body{
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;


}
.animation_wrapper{
    width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
.circle{
    width: 2%;
    height: 4%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 32.3%;
    left:23.3%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 4s;
}


img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="animation_wrapper">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/26/41/a9/2641a94b84a88671449faea04d29a647.png" alt="flash">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
```

It is my first experience on stackoverflow, so you can give some advice for writing questions too:)
Thanks for help !

Comment: In your JavaScript, you don't have any variable named `circle`. Please add the `circle` variable into your code.

Comment: var circle = document.querySelector('.circle'); 
Sorry I lose it when copied script

Answer (score -1):

I've made a library especially for that, 8 years ago:

https://github.com/yairEO/pathAnimator

You will an SVG path and then it's fairly easy to achieve what you're after.

Comment: I have to do this on JS without libraries :(

Comment: so copy my library to your source code (which is only a few lines) and then say you did it yourself :)

Comment: Or simply study what I did there, understand how simple it is, and re-create it